# VBA: matrix inverse

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do something simple: take a matrix in cells A1:C3 and write the inverse into cells E1:G3. This doesn't work and the error I get is "type mismatch". Why?

```
Sub f()
    Range("E1:G3").Value = g(Range("A1:C3"))
End Sub

Function g(m As Range) As Double()
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim minv() As Double
    r = m.Rows.Count
    c = m.Columns.Count
    ReDim minv(1 To r, 1 To c)
    minv = WorksheetFunction.MInverse(m)
    g = minv
End Function
```

Comment: where do you get the type mismatch? I.o.w.: at what line does the program break?

Answer (score 4):

`WorksheetFunction.MInverse` is returning a `Variant` containing the matrix not a `Double` array. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841265.aspx So the `Double` arrays and also the `ReDim` is not necessary.

But there is also another issue. Not all matrices are invertable. With an not invertable matrix `WorksheetFunction.MInverse` will throw an error. Better you use `Application.MInverse`. This will return `#NUM!` error as the `=MINV()` also would do.

```
Sub f()
    Range("E1:G3").Value = g(Range("A1:C3"))
End Sub

Function g(m As Range) As Variant
    Dim minv As Variant
    minv = Application.MInverse(m)
    g = minv
End Function
```

If the function must return a `Double()` array, then you must convert the `Variant` into that.

```
Function g(m As Range) As Double()
 Dim vMinv As Variant
 Dim dMinv() As Double

 vMinv = Application.MInverse(m)

 If IsError(vMinv) Then Exit Function 'what shall the Double() contain if m is not invertable?

 On Error Resume Next
 d1 = UBound(vMinv, 1)
 d2 = UBound(vMinv, 2)
 On Error GoTo 0

 'vMinv is one-dimensional
 If IsEmpty(d2) Then
  ReDim dMinv(1 To d1)
  For i = 1 To d1
   dMinv(i) = vMinv(i)
  Next
  g = dMinv
  Exit Function
 End If

 'vMinv is two-dimensional
 ReDim dMinv(1 To d1, 1 To d2)
 For i = 1 To d1
  For j = 1 To d2
   dMinv(i, j) = vMinv(i, j)
  Next
 Next
 g = dMinv

End Function
```

But the question is: what shall the Double() contain if m is not invertable? It can't contain error values.

Comment: I'm doing this for an assignment and the given function has to return a Double(). Is it possible? Which is the better practice between Variant and Double array?

Answer (score 0):

VBA functions can only return a one dimensional array. if you want to have it in two dimensions you has to do it by reference. Here i use a sub, byReference is default in VBA.

```
sub ret(a())
  redim A(2,2)
  A(2,2)=2
end sub


dim A() 
ret a
debug.print A(2,2)
```